# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/BeepManager Error

Tags: android, dalvik

I am trying to make a qrcode reader application.
I followed the instruction given on: 
http://www.androidaz.com/development/zxing-qr-reader-direct-integration

However I am facing error as :

```
 Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/BeepManager$1;
 Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/BeepManager$1;
```

Comment: maybe You have referenced the library AND put the jar into libs folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had multiple copies of the library for my project.
One in my bin lib as jar file
and other Referenced in my project & so open in my workspace.

So just removed one of the copy.